# Is there a vanilla Javascript alternative for .html()?

Tags: javascript, html, noscript

I'm wanting to create an opposite affect to `<noscript>`. I don't want the content to load at all if Javascript isn't enabled, which is why I'm not interested in a `display:none` alternative, which still loads but just hides.

I came across [this previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/488536) which has the desired affect (see updated answer).

HTML:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script type="text/html" id="content">
    <div class="test">HTML goes here</div>
</script>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#container').html($('#content').html());
});
```

Is there anyway I can do this with Vanilla Javascript? I want the contents of the `script` to render as functional HTML.

Comment: Yes - `.innerHTML`

Comment: There is [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML), though it has some big security issues. So be sure to do something against [XSS  attacks](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Cross-site_scripting).

Answer (score 1):

often what is done is to set up your html as:

```html
<html class="no-js">
<head>
  <script>(function(H){H.className=H.className.replace(/\bno-js\b/,'js');})</script>

  <!-- ... -->

</head>

<!-- ... -->

<div class="js-only">I only show up when js is enabled</div>

<!-- ... -->

</html>
```

and then have some css which hides that element

```css
.no-js .js-only {
    display: none;
}
```

the javascript replaces `no-js` with `js` in the `<html>` element which causes the div to display only when js is enabled